# Counting records from a select query.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to count records from a query. but I have a problem with it.

My query something like this :

```
SELECT name, address, mobile 
  FROM users 
WHERE city = 'beegin'
```

This query fetching multiple rows. So can I know is there a way to add count column to this select query to count how many records given from the query.

I cant use mysqli_num_rows() here. Thats why I am looking for a different solution.

Hope someone will help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, address, mobile, totalCount
  FROM users 
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) totalCount FROM users WHERE city = 'beegin') b
WHERE city = 'beegin'
```

Comment: and what's your real query? what's the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24681/discussion-between-ugnuku-and-jw)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS function like this

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS name, address, mobile FROM users WHERE city = 'beegin'
```

Just make second query after that.

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

But this method will not work if you use LIMIT